# jquery stop if result is null or undefined

Tags: jquery, null, undefined

I have a script that looks like this:

```
function bakVormShipping(targetClass) {
    $.getJSON('http://shop.com/cart/?format=json', function (data) {
        $.each(data.cart.shipping.methods, function (index, methods) {
            if (index == "core|2419|36557" || index == "core|2419|36558" || index == "core|2959|31490" || index == "core|2959|31491" || index == "core|2419|36556") {
                $('<strong/>').html('€' + (+methods.price.price_incl).toFixed(2)).appendTo(targetClass);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I get an undefined or null error in firebug when the "index" doesn't equals one of the indexes. How can I prevent that? Obviously something with `if (index == null)` etc. but I don't have a clue on how to do that in the right way.

Answer (score 1):

add a check for undefined above your if statement

```
function bakVormShipping(targetClass) {
$.getJSON('http://shop.com/cart/?format=json', function (data) {

    $.each(data.cart.shipping.methods, function (index, methods) {
        if(typeof(index) == "undefined"){
            return;
        }

        if (index == "core|2419|36557" || index == "core|2419|36558" || index == "core|2959|31490" || index == "core|2959|31491" || index == "core|2419|36556") {
            $('<strong/>').html('€' + (+methods.price.price_incl).toFixed(2)).appendTo(targetClass);
        }

    });
});
```

You might want to also check that the `data` object you recieve has the properties you are referencing, `data.cart`, `data.cart.shipping` and `data.cart.shipping.methods`

Comment: is it possible to do "nothing" when the result is null? And what do you mean with "has the properties you are referencing"? Is that necessary? I have limited skills and I'm doing this for the company I'm working for so any help is greatly appreciated. Anyway +1

Comment: You can just return if the index is undefined, I've edited my answer. You don necessary need to test that the properties exist, if you know your JSON structure hasn't changed.

Comment: Ok thx! Now firebug returns "data.cart.shipping is undefined". Perhaps I have to do a check there also? Or maybe that's what you meant with "has the properties you are referencing"?

Comment: Yeah I would test it before the $.each()

Comment: Ok that seems to do the trick! But now the "if (index == "core|2419|36557" || index == "core|2419|36558" etc" doesn't seems to function anymore. Can you help me with that?

Comment: are you sure that the `data` object has the properties you want? what does it say when you console.log(data) ?

Comment: it returns "Object { textpage={...}, cart={...}, shop={...}, more".